# Non-retina SKSpriteNode texture is pixelated

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am creating a circle shaped sprite node and getting pixelation in the non-retina version.  I am not changing the size of the sprite node anywhere in the code.  I am creating the non-retina version in `Photoshop` by going to `File>Save For Web>Changing` the size to 50%.  Each ball is a 50x50 PNG.

Here is how I'm instantiating each ball.

```
Ball *ball = [Ball spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"ball"];
```

Ball is a `SKSpriteNode` subclass.  The images below are taken at 100% scale in the simulator.  The non-retina images are pixelated in the simulator and physical device.  How can I make this asset look cleaner?

Retina ("ball@2x.png):
[image: retina]

Non-retina ("ball.png") [image: nonretina]

Comment: When you say they are looking pixelated, you are saying that they look different than the actual asset? What does your "ball.png" look like compared to "ball@2x.png" ?

Comment: Did you try using the Retina asset for non-retina, and creating a new Retina asset which doubles in size the original?

Comment: "ball@2x.png" is 50x50 pixels and "ball.png" is a 25x25 version of "ball@2x.png".  "ball.png" is not pixelated in finder, photoshop, etc.. It is only pixelated in the iPad (non-retina).

Comment: Have you verified it on an actual device?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D yes I have tried it on an iPad3 and iPad Mini.

Comment: And you ruled out for sure that this image is simply the matching lower resolution image for non-Retina (ie an issue of perception)? Ie Photoshop won't show you the actual pixel-image unless you load the png, not the psd. Finder/Preview image may not have been displayed as "actual size" or simply look better on a Mac display. Though the ball.png certainly looks somewhat oddly shaped. Hmmm try loading the @2x directly, set scale factor to 0.5 and place it next to the ball.png sprite for comparison.

Comment: Also, is this ball in a texture atlas (.atlas folder)? What happens if you make the @2x ball 100x100 so the scaled down version is 50x50? Also when scaling down Photoshop may apply linear or cubic filtering, make sure that's turned off.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D The ball texture is not in an atlas folder, it is in the images.xcassets folder.  I have tried all of the scaling modes in photoshop with no luck.  I have not tried doubling the size of the ball texture since it needs to be 25x25 points but I will give it a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably won't answer the original question exactly since the image referenced is 50x50, but for images that do not have a 1:1 ratio of height to width, it helps to first get the dimensions of the actual image and set the texture.

You might do it like this in Swift:

```
let image = imageAsset
let texture = SKTexture(image: image)
let factor = 0.5
let size = CGSize(width: image.size.width * factor, height: image.size.height * factor)
let node = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture, size: size)
```

The above would be used if you want to resize the image by 50%.  If you wanted the full-sized image, you would just use `image.size` for the size parameter for `SKSpriteNode` without the need for the `factor` variable.